# Visual Studio If statement always going through

Tags: visual-studio, if-statement

For some reason the If statements are always going through no matter what I put. Even if i did things like True == False or 0 == 1 it still goes through. What I am trying to do is detect if the text is null and set it to - so it doesn't error.

This is my code inside the button

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reg = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RegText.Text);
        if (reg == true);
        {
            RegText.ResetText();
            RegText.AppendText("-");
        }
        model = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ModelText.Text);
        if (model == true) ;
        {
            ModelText.ResetText();
            ModelText.AppendText("-");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < MaxCars; i++)
        {

            if (regos[i].Equals(Convert.ToString(RegText.Text)) || models[i].Equals(Convert.ToString(ModelText.Text)) || price[i] == Convert.ToInt32(PriceText.Text))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(regos[i] + " " + models[i] + " " + price[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end of your `if` statement

Comment: You can shorten your code to `if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RegText.Text)` and `if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ModelText.Text)`, btw.

Comment: I thought I am on the only one on the planet who make such silly mistakes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put ; at the end of every if that is causing an error.
This is the code with fix:

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reg = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RegText.Text);
        if (reg == true)
        {
            RegText.ResetText();
            RegText.AppendText("-");
        }
        model = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ModelText.Text);
        if (model == true) 
        {
            ModelText.ResetText();
            ModelText.AppendText("-");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < MaxCars; i++)
        {

            if (regos[i].Equals(Convert.ToString(RegText.Text)) || models[i].Equals(Convert.ToString(ModelText.Text)) || price[i] == Convert.ToInt32(PriceText.Text))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(regos[i] + " " + models[i] + " " + price[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```